# Can I add a directory on a newly added volume to an existing user?

Tags: disk, disk-usage

We are running out of disk space on the current machine, so we nfs mounted a new volume.

Can I add space on the newly mounted volume to our existing users? We have not limited users on disk space quota yet, but we will. So the to-be-allocated disk space should be under the control of disk space quota limit in the future.